# refreshing content inside dialogue box through JavaScript function

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot

I am stuck over a problem While dealing with primefaces charts.

**Problem**

When I click on a lineChart, a dialogue should appear which contains another linechart.

Sample Code

```
<p:lineChart id="chartOne" rendered="cond1"/>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogOne">
     <p:lineChart id="chartTwo" rendered="cond1"/>
</p:dialog>

<script>
   $('#chartOne').bind('jqplotClick',
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            dialogOne.show();
        }
   );
</script>
```

Now I am able to display dialogue on chart click but chart inside dialogue is not refreshing. I don't know much about refreshing content through JavaScript function.

**Update1:**

Condition is: **chartOne** should provide click over its whole canvas(not only datapoints or series). **chartTwo** should be rendered only if **dialogOne.show()** happens.

Any help...Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a solution to use a dynamic dialog.

From the documentation:

> Dynamic mode allows dialog to fetch it's contents beforeit's shown rather than on page load which is useful to reduce initial page load times. Default is false.

Just define your dialog like this:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogOne" dynamic="true">
```

---

**Update:**

To refresh the dialog from Javascript you can use `p:remoteCommand`. Example:

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p:dialog id="dialog" />
</h:form>
<p:remoteCommand name="updateDialog" update=":formId:dialog"/>
```

**Second update:**

To use the `p:remoteCommand` call `updateDialog()` from Javascript.

Comment: oops I missed an easy concept. thanks..It avoids loading dialogue content before it is shown. Also I need not to refresh dialogue content. It is helpful..

Comment: But it is still not answering my question. How to refresh content inside dialogue box through JavaScript function

Comment: @DipendraSingh If the answer I gave didn't answer your question, don't mark it as accepted. ;-) Apart from this, I've updated my answer.

Comment: k...your solution before updates, works fine in my case that's why I accept. But actual question was not answered properly. BTW thanks for updates...It works

Comment: @DipendraSingh I forgot to add how to call the remote command. Added it in an update. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p:lineChart id="chartOne" rendered="cond1" >
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.action}" update="chartTwo" oncomplete="dialogOne.show()" />
</p:lineChart>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogOne">
     <p:lineChart id="chartTwo" rendered="cond1"/>
</p:dialog>
```

on the method `action()` of your backing bean, you should ready the data for chartTwo.

The clickable part of the chart, as per the user manual, would be the series, not the entire chart. check

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/interactiveCharts.jsf

for more information and a working example.

Comment: event "itemSelect" is not triggered in my case. I think for chart click, binding is required

Comment: what version of primefaces are you running? From the PF 3.4 manual: 3.12.9 Ajax Behavior Events
itemSelect is one and only ajax behavior event of charts, this event is triggered when a series of a
chart is clicked. In case you have a listener defined, it’ll be executed by passing an
org.primefaces.event.ItemSelectEvent instance.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain my requirement properly. 'jqplotClick' is also working in case of click ouside datatpoints, but the itemselect event is dedicated for series selection only. Ultimately, my goal is to provide clickable chart(irrespective of datapoints) canvas so that the selected chart can be displayed in dialogue box.

Comment: Update your question then.